# Coinvariants of a homogeneous space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, homogeneous-spaces

We work over $\mathbb{C}$.  Let $G$ be an algebraic group, and let $X$ be an affine homogeneous $G$-variety.  Write $\mathbb{C}[X]$ for the algebra of regular functions on $X$, which is itself a $G$-module.

It is known, and easy to show, that the only $G$-invariant functions on $X$ are the constant ones.

My question is: what is known about the space of $G$-coinvariants on $\mathbb{C}[X]$?  In particular is its dimension bounded above by 1?

By $G$-coinvariant I mean a map of $G$-modules $\varphi:\mathbb{C}[X]\to\mathbb{C}$.